# ld: library not found for -lelementary

Tags: ld, macos-mojave

I try to run `make install`, but I get this error

> ld: library not found for -lelementary

What is elementary lib?
And where can I download it?

I searched several links for "ld: library not found for *", but it didn't help...

Update: I have solved the issue by adding path in CMake file. I have already installed efl by using homebrew "brew install efl". But the weird thing is that it doesn't point to the correct location, I have to add exact location "link_directories(/usr/local/lib) in the CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 0):

The library Elementary is part of EFL(Enlightenment Foundation Libraries). You can build it from the source code from [the download page](https://www.enlightenment.org/download), or install with [brew or git](https://www.enlightenment.org/docs/distros/osx-start.md).

Simply quoting the links, to install with brew (which is the simplest of the three options):

```sh
brew install efl
```

(And yes, I agree that the name "elementary library" is a terrible name for search engines. You only get results about school libraries.)

Comment: The weird thing is that it doesn't point to the correct location, I have to add exact location "link_directories(/usr/local/lib) in the CMakeLists.txt